# How to read output of a Reflective DLL?

Tags: malware, metasploit, c++

Reflective DLL Injection is one of the most interesting and best techniques to run custom code in memory.
I've been learning about it a lot, I've learned how to pass in inputs, But I can't figure out how to read in the output? I'm using C++.

The metasploit framework is able to get the output of the reflective dll,
https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/post/windows/manage/reflective_dll_inject.rb

But how can I do this in C/C++?

https://github.com/stephenfewer/ReflectiveDLLInjection

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You provide an example in the last link. And this is looking more like a programming question than a security question

Comment: @schroeder Hi, This is a programming question but in general this is a malware related question. My Question is about Reflective DLL Injection, The metasploit framework is able to pass input and read output from a reflective DLL, My question is, How is that done? And how can one do it by themselves?

Comment: Right, but you linked a C++ project. Doesn't that answer your question? If your question is about the coding details in the project, then this becomes purely a programming question.